# Integrating ADF with existing Services

Tags: hibernate, oracle-adf

We want to use ADF for our new project. However we do have an existing service and model layer that we want to reuse. This layer (built using spring and hibernate) is the heart of many other applications.

I'm struggling to find a way to reuse them in my ADF application. What's the best approach? I'm not able to find a good sample that talks about this use-case.

ADF gurus out there, your input will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ADF supports standards such EJBs and WebServices which, from my limited understanding, hibernate and spring expose. I think you just want to create ADF Data Controls for the services and EJBs you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make the most of ADF, try to use ADF binding layer (keywords to google: ADF Data Controls, ADF page definition) . It allows you (at least theoretically) to expose various service types(web services,EJBs, or pratically any java class...) to the upper ADF layers (ADF Faces for example) in service independent fashion, so you'll be able to communicate with those services in the same way as you would communicate with ADF Business Components.